# Direct reference of column names in python using python, psycopg2, and postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using python, psycopg2, and postgresql.  Looking for a way
to reference the column directly by name.  See example below.

```
TABLE testtable
testcolumn1 | testcolumn2 | testcolumn3 
------------+-------------+------------
 horse      | cow         | goat
 simple     | code        | test
 cant       | figure      | this


conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' user='me' password='pass'")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from testtable")
cursor_rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in cursor_rows:    
    print(row['testcolumn2'])

# the result of the loop should be 
cow
code
figure
```

Is there a way to directly reference by column name like this?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
import psycopg2.extras
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
```

[Documentation here. There is also support for named tuples.](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#real-dictionary-cursor)

Comment: Since the default is tuples, which are immutable, they will certainly be a bit more lightweight than dicts. I reckon the improved readability of the code more than makes up for that though.